# jQuery only rendering one select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a jQuery function which populates two drop downs, however at the moment only one renders, the other doesn't render at all.  However if i change the order (renderAccounts above renderGames) it's always the second render which occurs.

Here's the code:

```
 function renderCombos(games, accounts) {

    var renderGames = _.map(games, function (val) {
    return '<option>' + val + '</option>';
    }).join(); 

    $('select#gamescombo').html(renderGames).selectpicker('refresh');

    var renderAccounts = _.map(accounts, function (val) {
    return '<option>' + val + '</option>';
    }).join(); 

    $('select#accountscombo').html(renderAccounts).selectpicker('refresh');
 };
```

I don't know if this is related but i'm using Bootstrap for the combos and they're not appearing correctly either, i get an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'selectpicker'

My HTML is:

```
     <select class="selectpicker" id="gamescombo">
        <% _.each(games, function(item){ %>
        <option value="<%= item %>"><%= item %></option>
        <% });%>
    </select>   


    <select class="selectpicker" id="accountscombo">
        <% _.each(accounts, function(item){ %>
        <option value="<%= item %>"><%= item %></option>
        <% });%>
    </select>
```

Anyone know what i'm doing wrong?

Anyone got any idea?

Comment: did you include the `selectpicker` plugin in your page

Comment: Yes, i link to the bootstrap-select css file in my index

        `<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-select.css"/>`
Also it was working before i started using this function to populate it

Answer (score 0):

```
try 
 var  renderCombos = function(games, accounts) {


    var renderGames = _.map(games, function (val) {
    return '<option>' + val + '</option>';
    }).join(); 

    return renderGames;
 };

$.when(renderCombos()).then(function(renderGames) {
   $('select#gamescombo').html(renderGames).selectpicker();
});
```

Comment: Thanks but that didn't seem to work, error:
`Uncaught ReferenceError: renderGames is not defined`

Comment: set return value in then callback function

Comment: yeah i tried that too - no error but nothing happens, if i add a console.log under the join it outputs a string, but if i move it to under the `return renderGame;` it doesn't, so that suggests it falls over at that point?